# Crash in Iphone Simulator

Tags: ios

I have crash in iphone simulator:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NsRangeException', reason
>   NSMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:]: index 6
>   beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'

How I can fix it?
Thx

Comment: you are accessing object at index 6 of an array..while the array only has 6 objects[index - 0 - 5] .. try to debug it out

Answer (score 2):

This crash log explains that you have an array, but you are referencing an index of 6 whereas the array only has 6 objects in it meaning there should be 5 indexes because indexes start counting at 0 as annotated below:

> Array (
>
> 1st Object - Index 0
>
> 2nd Object - Index 1
>
> 3rd Object - Index 2
>
> 4th Object - Index 3
>
> 5th Object - Index 4
>
> 6th Object - Index 5
>
> )

So `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:` will not work because in either one of them, you have provided an index of 6, but there are only 5 indexes.

Here is an example of a working demo:

```
[array exchangeObjectAtIndex: 5 withObjectAtIndex: 2];
```

And that is totally valid because both indexes are valid for the array.

This is known as an `NSRangeException` which has a pretty obvious name, your index is out of range (too big!)